# Why does my jumping algorithm not work FPS-independent?

Tags: java, game-physics

I am trying to implement a simple algorithm for jumping, which should be FPS-independent. Unfortunately, the player jumps 1.6-1.9 blocks at 1-5 FPS, but 1.2 blocks at 60 FPS.

First of all, the acceleration becomes reduced by `GRAVITY * time for the last frame`. If the y-position is less than 0.15, the player is starting a new jump (`yAcceleration` is set to `JUMP_POWER`).

```
private static final float GRAVITY = 9;
private static final float JUMP_POWER = 4.4f; 
private static final float TOLERANCE = 0.15f;


private float yAccleration;
private float positionY;

//delta is in seconds
private void update(float delta) {
    yAccleration -= GRAVITY * delta;


    if(positionY <= TOLERANCE) {
        yAccleration = JUMP_POWER;
    } 


    float newYPosition = positionY + yAccleration * delta;
    if(newYPosition > 0) positionY = newYPosition;

}
```

This is the code which I use to call `update()` in my test example:

```
final float fps = 60;
final float deltaSeconds = 1f / fps;
while(true) {
    update(deltaSeconds);
    Thread.sleep((int) Math.round(deltaSeconds * 1000));
}
```

What do I have to change in order to make my algorithm FPS-independent?

Comment: It would be easier for you to work on vectors. But in 1d is kind of redundant indeed.

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right, and in my real game engine I use vectors, but in this simple example to reproduce the issue I assume it would be a bit an overkill. I have added the code used to call `update()` in this example.

Comment: I found out what my error is, but wasn't able to solve it yet. On starting jumping, yAcceleration is set to `JUMP_POWER`. After that, I add `yAcceleration * delta` to the position. When I run the game with a very low FPS rate, for example, 1 FPS, the acceleration (on starting jumping 4.4) is multiplied with 1. Therefore, I add +4.4 to `yPosition` which is not what I want (the player should jump 1-1.5 blocks).

Comment: You either want to have speed in units per seconds or units per frame. It seams that latter option is what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
final float fps = 60;
final float deltaSeconds = 1f / fps;
```

When i read this it was "WTF" right away. You cannot assume that delta will be 1/60th of a second. Moreover, it WILL BE NOT!

1/60 of a second is just your wait time. What about calculation? What about time required to actually get current time? What about redraw time? It all counts!

Insteed of using fixed unreal delta, just calculate actual time on every iteration.

```
final float fps = 60;
final float deltaSeconds = 1f / fps;
float t0=System.currentMilisecond();
while(true) {
    float t=Sytem.currentMiliseconds();
    float delta=t-t0;
    t0=t;
    update(delta);
    Thread.sleep((int) Math.round(deltaSeconds * 1000));
}
```

You can try to force your framerate, but you always have to calculate actual time difference.

Comment: No, in this example there is no further calculation and there is nothing drawn. The provided code in the `while(true)` loop is all that I am doing.

Comment: Game loop includes redraw. In your case if it does not, your calculations are in "different timeline". I just made bouncing ball for myself couple days ago and had no problem with gravity, bouncing, and 2d movement at all. All in all, your calculations on 1/60ths of a second is just unreliable.

Comment: There's also the issue of integration method - OP is using Euler which yields terrible results at large timesteps.

Comment: What is integration method?

Comment: `positionY = positionY + yAccleration * delta` performs *numerical integration* of vertical acceleration (which is also wrong) with respect to time. This particular method is very inaccurate for large timesteps (it "overshoots" the actual curve of Y position against time).